# How to iterate over three lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I have 3 the same lists how to dig in to id in one of the list?I tryed
create_card_on_the_board[0]['content']['id'] but i got Object is not subscriptable error [image]

```
    def create_card_on_the_board_call(self, id_list, card_count, card_name):
    global create_card
    responses = []
    for i in range(card_count):
        create_card = self.rest_api_helper.post_call(
            self.base_url + '/cards?' + 'key=' + test_config[
                'key'] + '&' + 'token=' + test_config[
                'token'] + '&' + f'idList={id_list}' + '&' + f'name={card_name}', headers=None)
        responses.append(create_card)
    return responses
```

Comment: Please post your code.Show us a minimal example please.

Comment: `.content` to get content. This gives you a bytestring you requested, probably the json. You should use `.text` instead to get the decoded one and then process the json. Or you let requests do that for you too: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 2):

what you have is a list of 3 HTTP responses.

```
create_card_on_the_board = [resp1,resp2,resp3]
for resp in create_card_on_the_board:
    data = resp.json()
    # now you have a python dict named 'data'  - assuming all responses have the same content you can do:
    print(f'id: {data["id"]}')
```

Comment: @ranger - not sure I understand your question. Do you understand the code that I have shared?

Comment: yes i have three different 'ids' but lets say I want select 1 list id only e.g                     f'id: {data["id"]}' here want to select id from list 0 f'id: {data[0]["id"]}' ?

Comment: `create_card_on_the_board[0].json()['id'] `

Answer (score 1):

`create_card_on_the_board[0]['content']` is bytes data. You’ll need to convert it into a dict first. E.g.,

```
myList = dict(create_card_on_the_board[0]['content'])
```